# Do we need to escape apostrophe and other symbols in React js

Tags: reactjs

Do we need to escape apostrophes and other symbols in React js?

Is this option dangerous? If yes what could you do?

```
<h2>Don't give up</h2>
```

[We know that JSX Prevents Injection Attacks.](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks)

So what if our file uses the js extension? What if jsx?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>YOU</h1>
      <h2>Don't give up</h2>
      <h2>{"Don't give up"}</h2>
      <h2>{"Don\'t give up"}</h2>
      <h2>Don&apos;t give up</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/escape-symbols-is-it-required-zzx0dc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: JSX does not prevent injection attacks.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't stop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, does it?

Comment: Guys answer the question, I don't need these votes. I need an answer. If u don't know, don't reply. Chiiiil

Comment: @vera, it's about innerHTML to my way of thinking. So, it's not the same what I wrote

Answer (score 1):

It's not dangerous, as you said, `JSX` prevents injection attacks by converting content into a string before rendering.

Comment: Writing <h2>Don't give up</h2> everything should work correctly? R u sure?

Comment: And what if our file has the js extension?

Comment: Yes will work fine, even thought you are using `.js` extension you are still using `jsx`